# Get a value to be squared until is greater than a input value

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Dlicari_loops
{
    public partial class Form5 : Form
    {
        int value;
        int maxvalue;
        public Form5()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            value = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            maxvalue = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            while (value < maxvalue)
            {
                try
                {
                    checked
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(value);
                        value = value * value;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add("You have reached the maximum the computer can do.");
                    break;
                }
            }
            listBox1.Items.Add("You have reached the maximum you had set.");
        }


    }
}
```

I'm not certain what is wrong with the code, I'm trying to make a list of a number being squared until it is greater than what the user puts in textBox1. For testing i'm putting 2 in textBox2 and 4 in textBox1.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error it just does nothing when I click the button that this code is under.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? Go step by step with a breakpoint and check what's going on. Maybe your event isn't even called.

Comment: @Dominik: there is no problem with the code you provded but you are handling mouseclick so you have to press the button using mouse but if you press the button with keyboard it does not work, are you sure you are clicking with mouse?

Comment: Is the button event handler actually tied to the button click event in your form?

Comment: I'm clicking with mouse and this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click); Is in the desginer if that is what you mean @DanielMann

Comment: then add `button1.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.button1_MouseClick);` in your Form5 constructor after `InitializeComponent();` statement

Comment: There it is working now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to write your code in `checked` block to get `OverflowException`.

by default all Arthimetic Exceptions are ignored.but if you want to raise `Arthimetic Overflow Exception` you need to use `checked context`.

In a checked context, if an expression produces a value that is outside the range of the destination type then it throws `Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow`.

Try This:

```
   try
    {
      checked
      {
      listBox1.Items.Add(value);
      value = value * value;
      }
    }
    catch 
    {
     listBox1.Items.Add("You have reached the maximum the computer can do.");
     break;
    }
```

**Problem :**  you have not registerd Mouse_Click Event with any handler to recevie MouseClick event.

**Solution 2:** add `button1.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.button1_MouseClick);` in your Form5 constructor after `InitializeComponent();` statement:

```
   public Form5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.button1_MouseClick);
    }
```

Comment: @Dominik: you need to use `checked` block did you try?

Comment: @Dominik: try with `checked` block in your try , it works perfectly, see my edited answer.

Comment: Yes I did but nothing happened when I pressed the button that this code is under.

Comment: @Dominik: try solution2 above used `Button_Click` Event instead of `Mouse_Click` and registerd event handler propely